# Delete Gridview row when paging is enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable, paging

I have a Gridview with paging enabled and delete button enabled. With the below code the row above the one for which the delete button is pressed gets deleted. I have also tried doing "dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows[rowIndex-1]".

The row values are in a DataTable only (not in Database).

Stuck badly

Need help or code to delete row when paging is enabled in gridview.

```
protected void GVRequest_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)
            {
                dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows[rowIndex]);
                drCurrentRow = dt.NewRow();
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

                GVRequest.DataSource = dt;
                GVRequest.DataBind();

                for (int i = 0; i < GVRequest.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    GVRequest.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text = Convert.ToString(i + 1);
                }
                //SetPreviousData();

                dt.AcceptChanges();

                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

                DataView view = new DataView(dt);
                DataTable dt1 = view.ToTable( /*distinct*/ true, "CartonID", "FileID", "FileMasterID", "DeptFileID", "RequestID");

                GVRequest.DataSource = dt1;

                DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What does  DataBind() do?

Comment: Made changes and tried with GVRequest.DataBind()..no Joy

Comment: Try putting  dt.AcceptChanges(); before the for loop

Comment: Thanks for your time Adil...Tried your suggestion but its not working...infact..when I press the delete button it is deleting a selected row from the first page only...rows on the other pages are not getting deleted

Comment: I feel it difficult to explain in comment, check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From OP comments**

> when I press the delete button it is deleting a selected row from the
>   first page only

When you are going to delete record from page after first page, you have to add the records on previous pages to get the index of the record in the DataTable as the DataTable does not know on what page you are.

With the code you have if you delete record at index 4 on second page you will actually delete record with index 4 on first page.

You need to calculate the index of DataTable keeping the PageNo and PageSize in expression as shown under.

```
int rowIndex = e.RowIndex + GVRequest.PageIndex * GVRequest.PageSize ;
```

*Note: I assume PageNo is zero for first page*

Comment: Adil my dear man..you are god sent....it works like a dream...Many Many thanks Bro...